# Delete rows in a csv file

Tags: c#

I have two files:  Example1.csv and Example2.csv, note they are not comma-separated, but are saved with the 'csv' extension.

Example 1 has 1 column which has emails address only
Example 2 has many columns in which it has the column that is there in example 1 csv file.

Example1.csv file

```
emails

abc@gmail.com

jhg@yahoo.com

...
```

...

Example 2.csv

```
Column1 column2 Column3 column4 emails

1 45 456 123 abc@gmail.com

2 89 898 254 jhg@yahoo.com

3 85 365 789 ...
```

Now i need to delete the rows in example2.csv that matches with data in example 1 file, for example: Row 1 and 2 should be removed as they both the email matches.

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\example2.csv");

 var emails = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\example1.csv");

 List<string> linesToWrite = new List<string>();


 foreach (string s in lines)
 {
     String[] split = s.Split(' ');
         if (s.Contains(emails))
             linesToWrite.Remove(s);

 }
 File.WriteAllLines("file3.csv", linesToWrite);
```

Comment: `String[] split = s.Split(',');` is it really that easy in your case? Real csv files may be a bit more complicated...

Comment: nvoigt i'm real newbie in coding

Comment: So what did you try, where are you stuck? You have an array `split` and need to find out if the 4th element is contained in `line` (horrible name btw, rename it to `emails` and you might find out what to do on your own). Can you do that? If not, why not?

Comment: Your "comma separated values" are not separated by commas in your example data. Is that a typo or is that your real data?

Comment: This code didn't work for me that's why i'm asking help! it's a typo

Comment: changed it's atypo Flater

Comment: need to use for loop to look if each email in example1.csv exists in example2.csv row if so delete whole row in example2.csv==> how can i do that i stuck in this step!

Comment: it appears you haven't really attempted to do this, or that you don't have an issue.  you explain what you want, and you give example code, but you've given no info on what the error is.  SO requires that you make an attempt to solve, which would mean you can describe what the problem is.  Even when nvoigt asked what's going on all you said is 'it doesn't work'.  Please clearly state what the error raised is (or the erroneous result) so we know what to fix.

Comment: Hey Keith when i used nvoigt code i got this error:using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>' requires 1type arguments !!

Comment: Now works like a charm :) I changed a little bit the code  string email = split[4];
                if (!line.Contains(email))
                {
                    linesToWrite.Add(s);
                }

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var emails = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\example1.csv").Skip(1));

File.WriteAllLines("file3.csv", File.ReadAllLines("C:\example2.csv").Where(line => !emails.Contains(line.Split(',')[4]));
```

It reads all of file one, puts all emails into a format where lookup is easy, then goes through all lines in the second file and writes only those to disk that don't match any of the existing emails in their 5th column. You may want to expand on many parts, for example there is little to no error handling. It also compares emails case-sensitive, although emails are normally not.

Comment: Thank you nvoigt just the error using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet>T>' requires 1type arguments !!

Comment: try adding `<string>` after `new HashSet` and before `(file...`.  Or try using `new List<string>` instead, it should give you a similar effect with a more familiar data structure

Answer (score 0):

Variable **line** is not string, but string array, same as lines, you are reading it in the same way as lines.

Also this line

```
if (s.Contains(line))
```

is not correct. You are trying to check if a string contains an array. If you need to check if a line contains an email from list, then this will be better:

```
if (split.Intersect(line).Any())
```

So, here is the final code.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\example2.csv");   
var line = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\example1.csv");

var linesToWrite = new List<string>();    

foreach (var s in lines)
{
    var split = s.Split(',');
    if (split.Intersect(line).Any())
    {
        linesToWrite.Remove(s);
    }

}

File.WriteAllLines("file3.csv", linesToWrite);
```

Comment: Hey DotNet I need to check if a Row contains an email from txt or csv file! or if an array contains a string .

Comment: Variable line contains array of emails from your file Example1.csv. Variable split contains a row from Example2.csv separated by commas. Intersect checks if a row from Example2.csv contains any email from Example1.csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Example1CsvPath = @"C:\Inetpub\Poligon\Poligon\Resources\Example1.csv";
        var Example2CsvPath = @"C:\Inetpub\Poligon\Poligon\Resources\Example2.csv";
        var Example3CsvPath = @"C:\Inetpub\Poligon\Poligon\Resources\Example3.csv";

        var EmailsToDelete = new List<string>();
        var Result = new List<string>();

        foreach(var Line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Example1CsvPath))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Line) && Line.IndexOf('@') > -1)
            {
                EmailsToDelete.Add(Line.Trim());
            }
        }


        foreach (var Line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Example2CsvPath))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Line))
            {
                var Values = Line.Split(' ');

                if (!EmailsToDelete.Contains(Values[4]))
                {
                    Result.Add(Line);                        
                }
            }
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Example3CsvPath, Result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years-old... But I've got some ideas from this and I like to share my solution...

The idea behind this code is a simple CSV, with maximum of about 20 lines (reeeeally maximum), so I've decided to make something basic and not use a DB for this.

My solution is to rescan the CSV saving all variables (that is not the same that I like to delete) into a list and after scanning the CSV, it writes the list into the CSV (removing the one I've passed *{textBox1}*)

```
    List<string> _ = new();

    try {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader($"{Main.directory}\\bin\\ip.csv")) {

            while (!reader.EndOfStream) {

                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                if (values[0] == textBox1.Text || values[1] == textBox2.Text)
                    continue;

                _.Add($"{values[0]},{values[1]},{values[2]},");

            }

        }

        File.WriteAllLines($"{Main.directory}\\bin\\ip.csv", _);

    } catch (Exception f) {
        MessageBox.Show(f.Message);

    }
```